# Pronunciation of die Höhle vs. der Hölle?

Tags: pronunciation

I want to make sure I am not hearing something that isn't there.  Take the sentence "Die Höhle in der Hölle" (The cave in hell). When I listen to the sentence on Google Translate, either fast speed or slow speed:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=de&tl=en&text=Die%20H%C3%B6hle%20in%20der%20H%C3%B6lle.&op=translate

I hear two slightly different "ö" sounds.  The "ö" in "die Hölle" sounds the same to my ears as the "ö" in "hören".  However, the "ö" in "der Hölle" sounds like a something between the "ö" in "hören" and the English word "hole", with the mouth slightly more open than the "hören" in "hören".

Do I have this right?  Or are they actually the same sound and I'm just imagining the difference?

Comment: All of the short/long vowel pairs in German differ not only in length. I would have hoped for an answer that explains that or for closing it as a duplicate if that has already been explained elsewhere. Unfortunately, a different close reason was found.

Comment: Closed, wow.  So much for german.stackexchange.com, too bad. Fun while it lasted.

Comment: Unfortunately, most dictionaries do not offer IPA transcriptions. For German, https://de.wiktionary.org does. For the German vowel system in general, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology.

Comment: @CarstenS Not all of them. *Alle Aale* have the same /a/ sound.

Comment: @Jan, are you saying that if you pronounce both of them with an elongated first vowel they become the same? They do not seem exactly the same to me. Very close, though, so it is possible that I am imagining it.

Comment: @CarstenS I’m saying that the *quality* of the two /a/ sounds is identical (but they differ in length) if I use a more standard, non-dialectal pronunciation.

Comment: @Jan, so if one says with comical exageration "Willst Du wirklich aaaaaalle Aaaaaale essen?", the two words are indistinguishable? Anyway, I agree that this pair is different from the others.

Comment: @CarstenS Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiktionary confirms this on the [IPA pronounciation page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:IPA_pronunciation_key)

where *Höhle* as well as *Hölle* are given as examples.

Summary is, that *Höhle* has the closed vowel pronounciation and *Hölle* the open one, similar to *lesen*, where the first *e* is closed and the second one open.

I strongly recommend to give a shot to established references instead of making assumptions based on hints as weak as the results of a text to speech algorithm.

Comment: Anmerkung: Die Frage zu beantworten und gleichzeitig für andere Mitglieder zu schließen, halte ich für einen fragwürdigen Vorgang.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich war tatsächlich etwas unschlüssig. Tatsächlich halte ich die Frage in der gestellten Form (gibt es einen Unterschied oder ist es Einbildung) für schließungswürdig und habe versucht, das  durch eine Antwort abzumildern. Was Carsten in seinem Kommentar anspricht, ist meiner Meinung nach, dass eine ähnliche etwas allgemeiner formulierte und substantiellere Frage sinnvoll ist. Vorhandene Fragen zur Vokallänge, die ich gefunden habe, kratzen aber arg an der Oberfläche.

Comment: das kann ich nachvollziehen. Ich war auch schon in ähnlichen Situationen, in denen ich eine Frage beantwortet habe, die ich zuvor zum Schließen geflaggt hatte. Doch wenn ich es bemerkt habe, habe ich mein Close-Vote wieder zurückgenommen. Hier besteht ja noch die besondere Situation, dass ihr Close-Vote unmittelbar zum Schließen der Frage geführt hat, ohne die Chance anderer Mitglieder, dem zuzustimmen oder das abzulehnen. (Ich hab noch nicht verstanden, wann bei Stack Exchange ein einziger Vote genügt.)

Comment: @guidot Kannst du vielleicht die Frage editieren, sodass die Frage nicht schließungswürdig ist? Dann könnten wir die Frage wieder öffnen. Das scheint mir hier die beste und konstruktivste Lösung.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich ich möchte es nicht beschwören, denke aber, dass ein Close-Vote eines Moderators ausreichend ist, wohingegen 5 nicht-Moderatoren voten müssen um eine Frage zu schließen

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Tatsächlich würde es damit eine andere Frage, und aus der vorhandenen kann ich nur "eingebildet oder Unterschied" herauslesen. Zu erraten, welche sinnvolle Frage gemeint gewesen sein könnte  und sie dahin abzuändern, scheint die Rechtfertigung eines normalen Edit (siehe [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)) bei weitem zu übersteigen. Das kann gerne einer der reopen-Voter tun. Ich habe meine Antwort zu einem Wiki geändert - damit keine Punkte mehr und leichter erweiterbar

Comment: @Allerleirauh: Das ist richtig, habe ich auch nachgefragen müssen.